# React Native - Push Stack Screen from another tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and my app struct look like below

-Home(tab)

--Archive

--PostDetails

-Search(tab)

-Profile(tab)

i want **push details screen** from **search tab** but in search navigation there isn't Push function, there is just navigate

so when use navigate to details screen from search tab, it's go details but when user go to search and from there go to details again, it goes previous details screen (it couldn't push stack). in Home tab screen push details work correctly

so how i **push details screen from search tab** like home tab ?

Navigate From Home to Details -> `navigation.push('Post', {data: item})`

Navigate From Search to Details -> `navigation.navigate('Post', {data: item})`

**MY Code (app.js) :**

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeStackScreen = () => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Archive" component={ArchiveScreen} />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="Post" component={PostScreen} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);

const MainTabs = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Home"
      options={{tabBarLabel: 'home', tabBarIcon: 'home'}}
      component={HomeStackScreen}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Search"
      options={{tabBarLabel: 'search', tabBarIcon: 'search'}}
      component={SearchScreen}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Profile"
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'profile',
        tabBarIcon: 'profile',
        cardStyle: {backgroundColor: '#121212'},
      }}
      component={ProfileScreen}
    />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dir = t('dir');
  const lang = t('lang');
  return (
    <PlayerProvider>
    <MenuProvider>
      <StatusBar
        barStyle="light-content"
        backgroundColor="#0000001a"
        translucent={true}
      />
      <NavigationContainer theme={MyTheme}>
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <MenuScreen {...props} />} drawerPosition={dir == 'ltr' ? 'left' : 'right'}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={MainTabs} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </MenuProvider>
  </PlayerProvider>
  )
};
```

Comment: You might want to post more complete code, it's not clear what is the details screen and how you currently navigate to it from Home and from Search

Comment: @Tamar , Navigate code added